# Change page and then change a Class

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, onclick

Is it possible to change a Class (by ID) after clicking a link that jumps to that page?
I've page 01, and when I click a link in Page 01, I want it to jump to Page 02 and then change a Class in Page 02.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the post that was deleted helped me a lot :)

I used this code to get the parameter

```
            function getParam( name ){
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
                else
                return results[1];
        }
```

Then removed the Class and added a new one

```
        var idPassing = getParam( 'id' );

        if(idPassing == "Publicidade"){
            functRemoveClassCurrent();
            document.getElementById("idFilterPublicidade").className+="current";
        }
```

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query string to the link on page01 that's then parsed on page load by a script page02, which will alter the relevant class/element on page02.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I'm assuming that you retrieve the `id` from page 1, select element by that `id` in page 2 and change its class. First you have to add URL parameters to the link and set its `href` attribute in page 01  to `https://yourlink.com?id=id-of-element-to-change`. In page 02, execute the following script when window is done loading the page:

```
window.onload = function () {
  let url = new URL(document.location.href);
  let id = url.searchParams.get("id");
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "your-class");
};
```